# avoiding a window.top redirect from an iframe

Tags: redirect, dom, iframe

I have a script, running on several websites that, when it detects a certain query string on the url, does the following:

- clears the whole document
- creates an iframe with the same relevant url
- injects the iframe in the body
- runs my proprietary code outside the iframe

I have come across a website, where things don't work because somewhere within that iframe, there is a redirect to the same url that affects the window.top.

Is there a way, through javascript, to prevent that redirect, if i don't have control of the code running on the website?